# how can I enumerate the databases of a sql server

Tags: sql-server, database

Given an instance of SQL server, what's the best way to enumerate the databases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL Server 2000+:

`select * from sysdatabases`

In SQL Server 2005+:

`select * from sys.databases`

The difference is subtle and barely worth mentioning for a one-liner like this. But depending on how much you're going to be accessing the system catalog, you may get some use out of this article:

[Querying the SQL Server System Catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189082.aspx)

You can also execute `sp_helpdb` without an argument to get basic information about all databases. (Pass in a database name as an argument to get more detailed information about that database).

Comment: Note that there is no `sys` schema in SQL 2000, is just `select * from sysdatabses`

Comment: @Remus Thanks, guess it's been too long since I needed 2000-compatible syntax!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT [name] FROM sys.sysdatabases
```

You could also get this from  `exec sp_databases;`

These commands will work from SQL 2000+.

Answer (score 0):

```
 EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; EXEC sp_spaceused'
```